# C++ STL Set Implementation in Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

What is the equivalent of C++ STL set<> in python 3?

If there is not an implementation what should I use in python to:

1) Store a list of numbers 
2) Find a not less than element in that list? like lower_bound<> of stl`s set

Comment: Some nitpicking: The [Standard Template Library (STL)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_Template_Library) was an inspiration for the [C++ standard library](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Standard_Library) but they are not the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `set()` function in Python to find unique values in the list if that is what you are looking for.

An example is as follows

```
temp_list = [1, 2, 3, 2, 1, 4, 5, 4]
unique_list = set(temp_list)
print(unique_list)
```

Results in

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Further, for getting the elements which are not less than certain `lower_bound`, you can do something like this.

```
lower_bound = 2
filtered_list = [i for i in unique_list if i >= lower_bound]
```

Comment: yes, but in that case the time complexity is O(N). Is it possible to do this in O(logN) time?

Answer (score 0):

I am not really a master of evaluating time-complexity, but I think one solution is to create a custom Generator to replicate the behavior.

```
def setLowerBound(x, lowerBound):
    if not isinstance(x, set):
        x = set(x)
    for value in x:
        if value < lowerBound:
            continue
        else:
            yield value
```

The above code will first get a set of all of the values, skip all the values that are *lower* than `lowerBound` and give back each value there after.

Example-of usage:

```
a = [1,2,4,5,6,12,5,12,5,1,2,79,6,12,6,1]
print(a)
for i in setLowerBound(a, 5):
    print(i)
```

Output:

```
[1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 12, 5, 12, 5, 1, 2, 79, 6, 12, 6, 1]
5
6
12
79
```